# if get_post_meta do something

Tags: php

I use this to show custom product number field:

```
<div class="phone-num">
Phone: <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_custom_product_number_field', true); ?>
</div>
```

How should nothing be displayed if the field is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you don't want the `<div class="phone-num">` to appear at all, here's how:

```
<?php
$phone_number = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_custom_product_number_field', true );
if ( ! empty( $phone_number ) ) : ?>
  <div class="phone-num">
    Phone: <?php echo $phone_number; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```